# Проблема с выводом картинок

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть код на яве, который выводит выпадающий список из базы без перезагрузки страницы:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
//$('#tipologia').change(function () {var tipologia = $(this).val();}
$('#filter_id').change(function () {
    /*
     * В переменную filter_id положим значение селекта
     */
    var filter_id = $(this).val();
    /*
     * Если значение селекта равно 0, то мы
     * не будем ничего делать
     */ 
    if (filter_id == '0') {
        $('#tipologia').html('<option value="0">- seleziona tipologia -</option>');
        $('#tipologia').attr('disabled', true);

        $('#profilo').html('<option value="0">- seleziona profilo -</option>');
        $('#profilo').attr('disabled', true);

    $('#tipologia').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#tipologia').html('<option>loading...</option>');
    $('#profilo').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#profilo').html('<option>loading...</option>');

    var url = 'filter.php';
    $.get(
        url,
        "filter_id=" + filter_id,
        function (all) {

            //console.log('MY RESPONSE!!!', all)

            if (all.resTipologia.type == 'error') {
                /*
                 * ошибка в запросе
                 */
                alert('error');
                return(false);
            }
            else {
                //============= выводим вид открытия =================//
                var optipologi = '';
                $(all.resTipologia.tipologi).each(function() {
                    optipologi += '<option value="' + $(this).attr('id') + '" data-icon="/ad/fm/files/Finestre/Tipologia/' + $(this).attr('nome_corto') + '.jpg" data-html-text="' + $(this).attr('nome_corto') + '">' + $(this).attr('nome_corto') + '</option>';
                });

                $('#tipologia').html('<option value="0">- seleziona tipologia -</option>'+optipologi);
                $('#tipologia').attr('disabled', false);
                //============= /выводим вид открытия =================//

                //============= выводим список профилей =================//
                var opprofili = '';
                $(all.resProfili.profili).each(function() {
                    opprofili += '<option value="' + $(this).attr('id') + '">' + $(this).attr('nome_corto') + '</option>';
                });

                $('#profilo').html('<option value="0">- seleziona profilo -</option>'+opprofili);
                $('#profilo').attr('disabled', false);
                //============= /выводим список профилей =================//
            }
        },
        "json"
    );
});
});
```

Как дополнить или исправить этот код таким образом, чтобы в выпадающем списке были изображения??? Спасибо.

Comment: @kiberchainik, Вы уверены, что пишите на "яве"? И вообще, в Вашем случае его следует величать не иначе как [Господин Великий JavaScript](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4). На "ты" с ним Вам общаться рановато пока. Проявите чуточку уважения.

Answer (score 1):

У вас с закрывающими скобками проблема - это первое.

Было:

```
            "json"
    );
});
});
```

Надо:

```
        "json"
    );
}
});
});
```

Второе - с чего вы решили, что стандартный select может отображать картинки? Тем более таким способом?

Попробуйте так:

```
<option value="2" style="background-image:url('/images/icon2.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; padding-left:25px;">Value2</option>
```

Если нужно больше вариантов - см. здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list

Comment: бекграунт не помог, но было бы очень уместно, спасибо

Comment: по коду и вопросу не ясно - вам где картинки нужны? в option или где-то еще?

Comment: да, нужно, чтоб в выпадающем списке были иконки, я находил примеры, настраивал, и работало только с теми списками селект, которые написаны в html, а если соединять с этим кодом, то не работает, ответ с данными от сервера приходит правильный (смотрел в консоли), а на странице в селектах показывает undefinit.

Comment: $(this).attr('nome_corto') - это что? если вывести именно это в console - что увидим?